# Как получить значение recaptcha с помощью js?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь вставить `recaptcha` на сайт.
Но возникла проблема, не могу получить значение `$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]` c помощью JS.

Js не будет обрабатывать это значение, он только примет его и отправит на сервер для валидации.

Я только хочу изначально проверить на JS, и отправить значение далее на сервер.

Как получить значение? HTML-код:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcePAATAAAAAGPRWgx90814DTjgt5sXnNbV5WaW"></div>
```

Comment: Рекапча, которая просто с флажком "я не робот", грузится через ифрейм, а потому доступ к нему у вас ограничен. Если вы про старую рекапчу, где вводятся сфотографированные номера домов - я не знаю, но уверен, что механизм там похожий

Comment: @br3t Видишь, а ты говорил, что JS не получит значения. Сейчас все движется в сторону JS, так то)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

[Вот сайт где это описано (официальный)](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

И код:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render for multiple widgets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        alert(response);
      };
      var widgetId1;
      var widgetId2;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        // Renders the HTML element with id 'example1' as a reCAPTCHA widget.
        // The id of the reCAPTCHA widget is assigned to 'widgetId1'.
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('example1', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('example2'), {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
        grecaptcha.render('example3', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The g-recaptcha-response string displays in an alert message upon submit. -->
    <form action="javascript:alert(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1));">
      <div id="example1"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="getResponse">
    </form>
    <br>
    <!-- Resets reCAPTCHA widgetId2 upon submit. -->
    <form action="javascript:grecaptcha.reset(widgetId2);">
      <div id="example2"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="reset">
    </form>
    <br>
    <!-- POSTs back to the page's URL upon submit with a g-recaptcha-response POST parameter. -->
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="example3"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```